# Probability distribution estimation

Tags: probability

The joint frequency distribution of two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given in the table below:

|  |  |  | $y$ |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|  | 1 | 0.10 | 0.05 | 0.02 | 0.02 |
| $x$ | 2 | 0.05 | 0.20 | 0.05 | 0.02 |
|  | 3 | 0.02 | 0.05 | 0.20 | 0.04 |
|  | 4 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.04 | 0.10 |

Using $\text{Var}(X)=\sum [x_i−\mathbb E(X)]^2 \cdot \mathbb P(X=x_i)$, we can define the conditional variance of $X$ for a given value of $Y$: $\text{Var}(X|Y=y)$. For example: $\text{Var}(X|Y=1)=\sum[x_i−\mathbb E(X|Y=1)]^2⋅\mathbb P(X=x_i|Y=1)$. Find $\text{Var}(X|Y=1)$.

In order to solve this I estimated this tables below
|       | y     |   |   |   |   |   |
|-  |:-:    |-  |-  |-  |-  |-  |
| x     |       | 1     | 2     | 3     | 4     |   |
|   | 1     | 0.10  | 0.05  | 0.02  | 0.02  | 0.19  |
|   | 2     | 0.05  | 0.20  | 0.05  | 0.02  | 0.32  |
|   | 3     | 0.02  | 0.05  | 0.20  | 0.04  | 0.31  |
|   | 4     | 0.02  | 0.02  | 0.04  | 0.10  | 0.18  |
|   |   | 0.19  | 0.32  | 0.31  | 0.18  |   |

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y = 1 | 0.53 | 0.26 | 0.11 | 0.11 |
| X | Y = 2 | 0.16 | 0.63 | 0.16 | 0.06 |
| X | Y = 3 | 0.06 | 0.16 | 0.65 | 0.13 |
| X | Y = 4 | 0.11 | 0.11 | 0.22 | 0.56 |

| W = E(X | Y = y) |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.79 | 2.13 | 2.84 | 3.22 |

So next should be estimation of of E(W). In last table I estimated half of this but I can't find how to estimate other half with values 0.19, 0.32, 0.31, 0.18 So can anybody help me how to find this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to calculate $\mathrm{Var}(X|Y=1)$? To calculate that, you can use the table (with rows $X | Y = y$ for $y = 1, 2, 3, 4$) you have computed. Since we are interested in the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y = 1$, you would be interested in the first row. Indeed, you can then simply imagine those four entries as defining your desired distribution, and you can then use the usual formulas to calculate the expected value (e.g. $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=1] = 0.53(1) + 0.26(2) + 0.11(3) + 0.11(4) = 1.82$), and the variance (i.e. using the first formula you wrote).